# Async Task never ends in simple API client. Deadlock?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, deadlock, asynchttpclient

I'm new to C# and I'm very likely misunderstanding the the proper usage of await,async and Tasks :)

I want to develop a class (`OWConnector`) that serves as API client for my app, for this purpose I develop a generic `PostRequest` method to perform POST request.

Unfortunately the app looks like is going into a deadlock when I user the auth method (that uses the generic method `PostRequest`).

Can you help me to understand where is the problem ? I marked in the code where the debugger await forever.

```
// the debugger get stacked here :(
```

Form method

```
 private void btnAnalyze_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    OWConnector api = new OWConnector(@"http://mywebsite.com/");
    Boolean didAuth = api.auth("myuser", "mypass");
    if (didAuth)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"success :)");
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show(@"failed :(");
    }
}
```

OWConnector class

```
class OWConnector
{
    private CookieContainer cookieJar;
    private HttpClientHandler handler;
    private HttpClient client;
    private Uri baseUri; 

    public OWConnector(string baseUrl)
    {
        baseUri = new Uri(baseUrl);
        cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        handler.UseCookies = true;
        handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        client = new HttpClient(handler);
        client.BaseAddress = baseUri;
    }

    public async Task<RequestResponse> PostRequest(string url, HttpContent data = null)
    {
        RequestResponse response = new RequestResponse();

        try
        {
            // the debugger get stacked here :(
            response.httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(url, data);  
        }
        catch (System.AggregateException e)
        {
            response.error = true;
            foreach (Exception ie in e.InnerExceptions)
            {
                response.errorMessage += ie.GetType().ToString() + ": " + ie.Message + "\n";
            }
        }

        return response;
    }

    public Boolean auth(string username, string password)
    {
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]{
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"form_name", @"sign-in"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"identity", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"password", password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"remember", @"on"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"submit", @"Sign In"),
        });

        RequestResponse r = PostRequest(@"/", content).Result;
        Boolean cookieFound = false;
        foreach (Cookie c in cookieJar.GetCookies(baseUri))
        {
            if (c.Name == @"ow_login")
            {
                cookieFound = true;
            }
        }

        return cookieFound;
    }
}

class RequestResponse
{
    public Boolean error;
    public string errorMessage;
    public HttpResponseMessage httpResponse;

    public RequestResponse()
    {
        error = false;
        errorMessage = @"";
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to wait for `PostRequest` to complete before you can access the `Result`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're blocking on an asynchronous operation by using `Task.Result`. You're doing [sync over `async`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx).

Your flow should be `async` all the way through from the event handler (that should be `async void`) all the way down (with `async Task`).

```
private async void btnAnalyze_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OWConnector api = new OWConnector(@"http://mywebsite.com/");
    Boolean didAuth = await api.authAsync("myuser", "mypass");
    if (didAuth)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(@"success :)");
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show(@"failed :(");
    }
}
```

```
class OWConnector
{
    // same as in OP...

    public async Task<bool> authAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]{
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"form_name", @"sign-in"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"identity", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"password", password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"remember", @"on"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"submit", @"Sign In"),
        });

        RequestResponse r = await PostRequest(@"/", content);
        Boolean cookieFound = false;
        foreach (Cookie c in cookieJar.GetCookies(baseUri))
        {
            if (c.Name == @"ow_login")
            {
                cookieFound = true;
            }
        }

        return cookieFound;
    }
}
```

The reason for the deadlock is probably the fact that there's a `SynchronizationContext` and you are blocking on a task that need to post to the SC to complete (hence, deadlock). While `async` all the way solves the issue you should also be aware of `ConfigureAwait(false)` that disregards the captured SC. So an even better `authAsync` would be:

```
public async Task<bool> authAsync(string username, string password)
{
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]{
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"form_name", @"sign-in"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"identity", username),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"password", password),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"remember", @"on"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>(@"submit", @"Sign In"),
    });

    RequestResponse r = await PostRequest(@"/", content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Boolean cookieFound = false;
    foreach (Cookie c in cookieJar.GetCookies(baseUri))
    {
        if (c.Name == @"ow_login")
        {
            cookieFound = true;
        }
    }

    return cookieFound;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's works like a charm! So as a rule of thumb all the method calls in my call stack has to be async starting from the generation of the event, right ?